# Should I restart application server on every change using ExpressJS/Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am working on Node.JS applications right now and I'm going with ExpressJS as MVC framework. The point, from now, is: should I restart the server (`node app.js`) every time that I make some change on `app.js`?

If so, there's no way to pass through? It's a little boring to do this.

Comment: you can use npm's forever package (or something like it) to do this for you automatically on source files changing or when the app crashes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Obviously if you do not restart the server you will not see the results of any changes you have made, however you do not have to do this manually. There are many options that will automatically restart the app when you change the source files, the most popular being:

- [nodemon](https://www.npmjs.org/package/nodemon)
- [forever](https://www.npmjs.org/package/forever)
- [supervisor](https://www.npmjs.org/package/supervisor)